# Unable to connect to database in codeigniter in MAMP

Tags: php, codeigniter, mamp

Hi I am using MAMP and Codeigniter. The Codeigniter **version is 2.x** I built an application on Linux [LAMP] now I want to move the application to MAC Book. When I Open the Localhost it shows me error of :

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 347

Now what could be the reason? My Credentials are correct but maybe I am trying to access it in wrong manner?

```
  $active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'biz_prov';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

In LAMP I had to do localhost/project but here I Have **localhost:8888/projectname** can this be the possible reason?

Comment: What's the port your mac's mysql listen on?

Comment: how can i know that ? I just see root@localhost

Comment: Does your username and password allow you access to PhpMyAdmin (if you use it), or other manual access to database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be couple of reasons for this issue:

- **dbdriver**:   Replacing **mysql** with **mysqli** worked for me, if doesn't work, you can also try with **sqlsrv**

  ```
  $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';  // mysqli for mac, 

  $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';   //mysql for windows
  ```
- **pconnect**: You may need to set to **FALSE**

  ```
  $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
  ```
- And,**Credentials**. Do verify your username and password, cuz it gives the same error when credentials doesn't match.

One thing at a time, You may not need to modify all, but it won't hurt to try when something doesn't work :)

Sample for reference:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost'; // try using ip or ip and port if needed(trying doesn't hurt).
$db['default']['username'] = '*****'; // provide your username
$db['default']['password'] = '*****'; // provide your password
$db['default']['database'] = 'storedb';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';  // mysqli for mac, mysql for windows
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `localhost:port` for `$db['default']['hostname']`,so it should look like this in your case

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost:8888';
```

Let me know if you have any further queries